# How to compare decimal with EF4 and Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I need select with decimal field...

this work!!

```
var id = context.Localizacoes.Where(x => x.Horario == data && x.IdFuncionario == id_funcionario).FirstOrDefault().IdLocalizacao;
```

but I add decimal var for compare.. "latitude"

```
 id = context.Localizacoes.Where(x => x.Horario == data && x.IdFuncionario == id_funcionario && x.Latitude == latitude).FirstOrDefault().IdLocalizacao;
```

return this error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `FirstOrDefault` returns null

Try to check returning value then access your property:

```
var result = context.Localizacoes
            .Where(x => x.Horario == data && x.IdFuncionario == id_funcionario && x.Latitude == latitude)
            .FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null)
   id = result.IdLocalizacao;
```

Comment: tks work 

But falls into another problem, the line was a line that I sent in my exception. 

When there is a (date, lat, long) in the bank returns an exception of composite primary key. 

So I search the database which is the ID for that record (the line from the beginning of the post) 

The problem is, there is an error when I try to insert the record because it already exists with (date, latitude, longitude), however when I try to retrieve the record it returns null. 

Was reading about precision decimal field, will have to configure something in my Model, about the accuracy?

Comment: @NilberVittorazzi At StackOverflow staying on topic is "sacred". We don't chain questions. Your immediate question is answered. If you've got a different question, even though it is related, you should start a new question.